# Open AI API: Only getting array of metadata, no response

Tags: php, curl, openai-api

I am experimenting with Open AI API using a PHP curl request.  The returned data from the API is only an array of metadata, no response to the prompt.  I have read the open ai guidelines and searched for an answer to this problem but haven't found anything - I guess I have made a simple mistake somewhere.

Code:

```
$Url            = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions";
$OpenAIModel    = "text-davinci-003";  //"model-id-0";
$Headers  = [
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $ApiKey . ''
];

$Messages               = "What is th capital of France and how many people live there?";
//$Messages             = array("role" => "user", "content" => "What is th capital of France and how many people live there?");
//var_dump($Headers);
//define data
$Data = array(
    'model' => $OpenAIModel,
    'prompt' => $Messages,
    //'messages' => $Messages,
    'max_tokens' => 7,
    'temperature' => 0.5,
    'top_p' => 1,
    'best_of' => 2,
    'frequency_penalty' => 0.0,
    'presence_penalty' => 0.0,
    //'stop' => '["\n"]',
);

/*<note>Initiate CURL request and specifies settings. */
$Ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $Headers);
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($Data)); 

$Response = curl_exec($Ch);  /*<note>Execute curl request. */
```

Here is the data returned by the curl request/API.

```
array (size=37)
  'url' => string 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions' (length=37)
  'content_type' => string 'application/json' (length=16)
  'http_code' => int 200
  'header_size' => int 739
  'request_size' => int 207
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 2.649047
  'namelookup_time' => float 0.031485
  'connect_time' => float 0.04659
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0.141851
  'size_upload' => float 198
  'size_download' => float 292
  'speed_download' => float 110
  'speed_upload' => float 74
  'download_content_length' => float 292
  'upload_content_length' => float 198
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.141891
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string '104.18.7.192' (length=12)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 443
  'local_ip' => string '192.168.1.136' (length=13)
  'local_port' => int 54910
  'http_version' => int 3
  'protocol' => int 2
  'ssl_verifyresult' => int 0
  'scheme' => string 'HTTPS' (length=5)
  'appconnect_time_us' => int 141043
  'connect_time_us' => int 46590
  'namelookup_time_us' => int 31485
  'pretransfer_time_us' => int 141851
  'redirect_time_us' => int 0
  'starttransfer_time_us' => int 141891
  'total_time_us' => int 2649047
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake in the code.  Further down (not included in the above code) there was an error handling function that included:
$Response = curl_getinfo($Ch);
This overwrote the $Response that was stored in:
$Response = curl_exec($Ch);
curl_exec return the actual data response from the API (amongst other metadata)
curl_getinfo returns information about the last transfer but not the returned data itself